# Saving Images to PDF but always getting the same Image

Tags: java, android, pdf

My first Post here and I'm not a really good programmer though.
Anyways. I have this Project where I need to provide a new feature for an app. 
The app generates via QR- Scanner a List of participants. My task was to provide a Paint for giving a Signature for each participant. 
Everything works fine so far with this Signature and it is also saving the Images to the Folder I want to. 
In my "PDF- Creator" class I got the Method creatPDF, where it should put first the unique-number of a participant and then the Signature he/she gave. 
Actually its all working so far but like my header says I always get the same picture for every participant. Here is some Code:

This is for filling an Array with all the Images in my Folder:

```
        String[] signatures = getSignatureFiles();
        Image[] efnSignatures = new Image[signatures.length];
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for(int i = 0; i<efnSignatures.length; i++){                
            fileName = signatures[i];
            File myPath = new File(directory,fileName);
            String url = myPath.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, stream);
            efnSignatures[i] = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            efnSignatures[i].setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
        }
```

Here is the Method "getSignatureFiles:

```
private String[] getSignatureFiles(){
    ContextWrapper tcw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    File directory = tcw.getDir("Signatures", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String[] files = new String [directory.listFiles().length];
    int countFiles = 0;
    for (File f : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()){
            files[countFiles] = f.getName();
            String name = f.getName();
            Log.i("file names", name);
            countFiles = countFiles+1;
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

And finally here is supposed to be the part, where I add the Images to the PDF:

```
for (int i = 0; i < signatures.length; i++) {
            insertCell(table, dummyList.get(i), Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(efnSignatures[i]);
            table.addCell(cell);
        }
```

The Problem is, I'm working in a Group and wasnt responsible for this PDF- Creator, however I need to get it working now. I hope this Code will give at least a bit of understanding what my problem is and somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance already

Comment: What is the source of your Bitmap and Image classes? Do you need to create a new ByteArrayOutputStream for each Image, and close it after use (a SWAG on my part to be sure)?

Comment: Ah, it's Android. [tag:android] tag added.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your Question right. But I create the Images with opening a new Fragment "CaptureSigantureFragment" that creats a new Object of another Class I called "Signature". Signature provides then the Methods for Painting and also a save Method:
{_out = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
v.draw(canvas);   mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, _out);
_out.flush();
_out.close();}

Comment: I was wondering if you should create a new ByteArrayOutputStream **inside** of your for loop.

Comment: As an aside, you don't want to post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26864725/edit).

Comment: Alright. Sorry for making this mistakes. Just signed in here some minutes ago :)

Comment: And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

So just changed like you said and its creating a new ByteArrayOutputStream now in the loop and actually its working!

Looks like this now:

```
for(int i = 0; i<efnSignatures.length; i++){    
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            fileName = signatures[i];
            Log.i("name:", fileName);
            File myPath = new File(directory,fileName);
            String url = myPath.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.i("PDF_Creator_url:", url);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, stream);
            efnSignatures[i] = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            efnSignatures[i].setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
        }
```

Didnt expect to find a solution that quick!
Thank you very much! 
Best help I could find!

Comment: Please know that my recommendation was a guess, which is why I did not post it as an answer, and so you might want to await blessing of this guess by someone in the know. Also my reflex whenever I use a Stream is to close it after use, and I suspect that you should also do that here, but again, I am ignorant in the ways of Android.